# select row with error during insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

In SQL Server, when i try to insert using a direct select statement from a table, i get an error

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'CLONED' to data type int.
```

Is there any way i can see the specific row which is throwing this error?

```
insert into manual_defect SELECT <long list of columns> from xyztable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try catches and throw out the row number but the best way I have found to debug quickly is selecting the top 1000, then 100 and keep doing that until you find the row(s) that is causing the issue.  Just a suggestion

Comment: how can i do this.. for DELETEs it would have been easy deleting top 1000 and then next 1000 and so on.. but for select, what is the best way

Comment: Else, if i'm able to ignore the error column and continue with inserts , it serves my purpose

Answer (score 0):

One of the columns you are selecting from xyztable is of type nvarchar and the matching column in manual_defect is an int. You need to find the rows in xyztable where that column has something in it that doesn't convert to an int.

```
SELECT * FROM xyztable WHERE NOT ISNUMERIC(yournvarcharcolumn + '.0e0')
```

IsNumeric checks if a value, which in this case is going to be a string, can convert to a numeric type. By appending ".0e0" before checking we make sure that only integers will work, because any other numeric type in string format stops being a valid numeric type when you add that to the end.

If you really only want to find the single row throwing the error you've quoted, then this would work more quickly:

```
SELECT * FROM xyztable WHERE yournvarcharcolumn = 'CLONED'
```